# WPF- Is there a way to make a TabContol ignore CTRL-Tab and still fire CTRL-TAB keybindings on the parent window?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` in the mainwindow of my app. I also Have a keyBinding for `CTRL-TAB`. However, whenever the `TabControl` is selected and `CTRL-TAB` is pressed the keybinding is not triggered because the `TabControl` handles the input and cycles through the tabs.

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to subclass TabControl and override the OnKeyDown method:

```
public class TabControlIgnoresCtrlTab : TabControl
{
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Key == Key.Tab) return;
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }
}
```